# JQUERY UI AUTOCOMPLETE NOT WORKING ON TEXTBOX asp.net

Tags: asp.net, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I have several textboxes in an aspx page.
I am using jquery UI autocomplete feature on several of those textboxes.

It works fine on the first textbox (inside one DIV) but on textboxes inside several DIV's it doesn't work.

Are there any known issues for this ?

Just to test it I have copied the same textbox and put it within the first DIV and it works (2 textboxes together, both work), but when it is back on its place (various DIV's deep), it not longer works.

The code gives no errors.

I am using the very basic autocomplete:

```
$("#txtsearch").autocomplete({
                         source: availableTags, minLength: 0
                     }).focus(function () {
                         $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
                     });

<asp:TextBox ID="txtsearch" runat="server"  CssClass="searchfields" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Do you possibly need to set `ClientID` as well as `ID`?

Comment: What's with the CAPS?

Comment: I assume you mean as per answer below by causita ? Nope, it didn't work either.  @Izzy, you mean the DIV ? Sorry, no idea, I just used capitals, don't know why, my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

try resolving the name in Jquery using this syntax

```
$('#<%=txtsearch.ClientID%>').autocomplete({
                         source: availableTags, minLength: 0
                     }).focus(function () {
                         $(this).autocomplete("search", "");
                     });
```

Comment: sorry, still doesn't work...and your new code gives no errors. By the way, if I want to use your syntax using cssclass as a reference for autocomplete  instead of the textbox id, how is it done ? I tried but gives an error.

Comment: Can you post your code with the Divs that you are having problem with? If you are using classes then you just use regular jquery class selector.

Comment: also try changing this  CssClass="searchfields" to class="searchfields" then in jquery just do $(".searchfields").

Comment: sorry but the code is huge...lots of textboxes, gridview, etc I have however made a small test with several nested div's and seem to work (totally new page), so I assume the div's is not the issue...:(

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in autocomplete function where it ends like

```
$('#txtHRProc').autocomplete({
   // rest of codes
})
.bind('focus', function () { $(this).autocomplete("search"), $(this).val(); });
```